# Any way to share data between Polymer components?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Currently I have two Polymer components that share a great amount of data. You can see here:

```
<polymer-component1
      series="{{series}}" 
      stackhelper={{stackhelper}} 
      stack={{stack}}
      controls={{controls}} 
      camera={{camera}} 
      threed={{threed}} 
      scene={{scene}} 
      renderer={{renderer}}>
</polymer-component1>
<polymer-component2 
      stackhelper=[[stackhelper]]
      stack={{stack}} 
      controls={{controls}} 
      camera={{camera}} 
      threed={{threed}} 
      scene={{scene}} 
      renderer={{renderer}}
      guiobjects={{guiobjects}}>
</polymer-component2>
```

This is working fine right now but whats the best practice about sharing data? Any way to share all the properties between two components?

Comment: Redux is quite nice for managing shared state and there is Polymer bindings available. https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to share data through data binding, just as what you're doing. You can share any property, not just strings and numbers. e.g. assuming you have an object

JS

```
data = {
    series: "",
    stackhelper: "",
    stack: "",
    controls: "",
    camera: "",
    threed: "",
    scene: "",
    renderer: "",
}
```

Your code can be rewritten like this.

HTML

```
<polymer-component1 data="{{data}}"></polymer-component1>
<polymer-component2 data="{{data}}"></polymer-component2>
```

Comment: That would make the html tag look cleaner but I think it would be less practical. Yes, as I can see my method is ok and common. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Polymer 2 one element can just inherit the properties by extending it.

```
class MyElementSubclass extends MyElement {...}
```

Or you create an element with just the properties both need and then both components extend the parent. You can find this [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements) scroll down to Extending an existing element

Comment: But I need to share the **values** of the properties between the components. Not just the properties or methods. Not sure if that would share the values

Comment: Oh sry i guess is misunderstood you but danielx is right then i acually use redux for sharing a state between components :-)